# Gnome Settings "Automatically Delete Temporary Files"

Tags: gnome

What does the setting "Automatically Delete Temporary Files" actually do? Two parts to this question: (1) what is meant by "automatically" ? Every day? Every login session? Every millisecond? (2) What is meant by "temporary files"? Are these the files in the `/tmp` directory? That seems to be cleaned every time I reboot, in spite of having this option in GNOME's Settings disabled.